# XSL using a variable with when test

Tags: variables, xslt

I am having much difficulty trying to operate on a variable value using `when test=...`.

When I output `$tcbrand` it outputs `'Direct'` but when I operate on it, it returns `false` and hits the otherwise block. What am I doing wrong?

```
    <fo:static-content flow-name="header-normal" font-size="10pt">  

                <xsl:variable name="tcbrand" select="smf:entity[@type='d2501b79-f888-4aa8-9fcf-a667a4c47c84']"/>

                <fo:block font-size="10pt" text-align="left">
                    <fo:inline font-weight="normal">Brand: <xsl:value-of select="$tcbrand"/></fo:inline>
                </fo:block>

                <xsl:choose>
                    <!--<xsl:if test="$image = 'hello' ">-->
                    <xsl:when test="string($tcbrand)='Direct'">
                        <fo:block text-align="right" space-before="0mm">
                            <fo:external-graphic src="url('C:\Program Files (x86)\numerointeractive\whitemail\Images\18-30.png')" />
                        </fo:block>             
                    </xsl:when>

                    <xsl:otherwise>                         
                            <fo:block text-align="right" space-before="0mm">
                                <fo:external-graphic src="url('C:\Program Files (x86)\numerointeractive\whitemail\Images\ecom2.jpg')" />
                            </fo:block>             
                    </xsl:otherwise>                                
                </xsl:choose>
```

This is the xml that gets generated, which I am operating on:

```
 <smf:entity id="48659" type="d2501b79-f888-4aa8-9fcf-a667a4c47c84" confidence="1.0" author="2e0b99b3-9cba-4736-a59b-fe00b5f62871" validated="true" preferred="false" requiresComponentExtraction="false" changeTime="2012-11-26T14:47:28.840Z" nonPersistedId="false" modified="false">
           <smf:value>Direct</smf:value>
        </smf:entity>
```

Comment: Can you include the relevant bit of the XML?  Maybe there are extra leading or trailing whitespace characters that are confusing things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<xsl:variable name="tcbrand" select="smf:entity[@type='d2501b79-f888-4aa8-9fcf-a667a4c47c84']"/>
```

will set the `tcbrand` variable to the `smf:entity` element.  The string value of an element is the concatenation of all its descendant text nodes, which for

```
<smf:entity id="48659" type="d2501b79-f888-4aa8-9fcf-a667a4c47c84" confidence="1.0" author="2e0b99b3-9cba-4736-a59b-fe00b5f62871" validated="true" preferred="false" requiresComponentExtraction="false" changeTime="2012-11-26T14:47:28.840Z" nonPersistedId="false" modified="false">
       <smf:value>Direct</smf:value>
    </smf:entity>
```

means a newline, seven spaces, "Direct", another newline, and another four spaces.  This is not equal to "Direct".  I can think of three possible fixes:  you could use

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

at the top of your stylesheet, which will cause it to completely ignore all whitespace-only text nodes in the input document, you could `normalize-space` when doing the test:

```
<xsl:when test="normalize-space($tcbrand)='Direct'">
```

or you could take the value of the child `<smf:value>` element instead of the parent `<smf:entity>` one, either at the variable declaration point

```
<xsl:variable name="tcbrand"
  select="smf:entity[@type='d2501b79-f888-4aa8-9fcf-a667a4c47c84']/smf:value"/>
```

or at the point of the test

```
<xsl:when test="$tcbrand/smf:value='Direct'">
```

Comment: Problem solved, your help has made my day! I have only spent about 6 hours looking at this issue! Thanks for the excellent response and knowledge share. :)

Comment: @user1853610 Glad it helped, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  When you get an answer that solves your problem it's good manners to mark it as _accepted_ by clicking the tick mark to the left.  Building a track record of accepting good answers will make it more likely that people will answer your other questions in future.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your variable `tcbrand` contains a document node and not a text string in your example.

I suspect that the reason it is printing `Direct` in your example is because this is the text content of the selected node. This will evaluate to false in the test attribute because the variable doesn't contain the literal string `Direct`.

To select the text value from the selected note use `/text()` in the variable declaration, e.g.

```
 <xsl:variable name="tcbrand" select="smf:entity[@type='d2501b79-f888-4aa8-9fcf-a667a4c47c84']/text()"/>
```

The use of `text()` is covered here in ['When should I use /text() at the end of my XPath expression?' on the site xquery.com](http://www.xquery.com/tips_and_tricks/using_text_in_XPath.html):

> You have probably seen a lot of examples that use /text() at the end of XPath expressions, and you might be wondering, Should I do the same? Are there any drawbacks?
>
> There are cases in which you do want to append /text() to your XPath expression to force your XQuery to consider the text value of your XPath expression; the typical case is when you want to dynamically create the value of a result element; something like this:

```
<title>{$doc//book[1]/book-title}</title>
```

> … generates this output:

```
<title>
    <book-title>La Divina Commendia</book-title>
</title>
```

> However, if what you are trying to create is actually this:

```
<title>La Divina Commendia</title>
```

> … then you need to instruct XQuery to use the text value of the  element, and an easy way to do that is appending /text() to the XPath expression:

```
<title>{$doc//book[1]/book-title/text()}</title>
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, unfortunately if I add /text() it does not work. It also then does not actually output the brand in the lines below. If I use <xsl:when test="contains($tcbrand,'Direct')"> then it will work so the text is in there! Any other ideas? Your help is much appreciated

Comment: @user1853610 if `contains($tcbrand,'Direct')` works then it is almost certainly that you have extraneous whitespace or other characters around the element value.  We need to see the input XML to be sure, please edit the question and add this.

Comment: I have added the XML above that is being used. Looks okay though.